# Can i have multiple virtual env on same computer withsame name

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am making the base skeleton of some Django project files so that I can put them on git and whenever I need to make a new Django site I can grab the files from git and start a blank project.

In my fabfile, I'm generating a virtualenv named `virutalenv`.

I just want to know that if I need to make many sites on single computer then all will have same not but they will be in the project directory.

Is that ok?

Comment: Not much of a question here, but you can try it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to create multiple `virtualenv`s with the same name; they must be in different parent directories, however.

Alternately, you could create multiple virtualenvs in the same parent directory, but with different names.